# I am unable to open Jupyter notebook in Anaconda due to Application notebook launch error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am learning anaconda,everything was fine initially but now jupyter notebook not working I am struck,Pleas help I tried reinstalling and every method I got but none work.Below is the error message I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 235, in _resolve_classes
klass = self._resolve_string(klass)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 2009, in _resolve_string
return import_item(string)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\utils\importstring.py", line 30, in import_item
module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_server.contents'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 277, in launch_instance
return super().launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 1044, in launch_instance
app = cls.instance(**kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 555, in instance
inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1295, in __new__
inst.setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1338, in setup_instance
super(HasTraits, self).setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1314, in setup_instance
init(self)
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 226, in instance_init
self._resolve_classes()
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 238, in _resolve_classes
warn(f"{klass} is not importable. Is it installed?", ImportWarning)
TypeError: warn() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'stacklevel'
```

Comment: What version of Jupyter are you running? It seems this is [a bug in one of the latest releases](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/7048)

Comment: You ahve conflicting python installations. If you want to stick to anaconda, uninstall the one at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311

Comment: Ia am using latest conda version v23. 5.0

Comment: I am currently using Jupyter notebook in Vscode which works fine.

Comment: Somehow I am able to reduce error by using install --update notebook to.                                          Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:

\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter- notebook-script.py", line 6, in from notebook.notebookapp import main ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.notebookapp'

Answer (score 9):

I had presumably the same issue, and following the discussion in the report linked by esqew, I fixed it with

```
conda install traitlets==5.9.0 -c conda-forge
```

Comment: Sure I will try this thx

Comment: This fixed this issue for me.

Comment: This command is running since last 15mins. Not sure if it will help me fix the issue:

WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(537): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 1.6.0.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 1.6.0
done
Solving environment: \

Answer (score 7):

The following solved my problem:

```
pip install --upgrade notebook
```

Before:

```
❯ pip freeze | grep notebook
notebook==6.4.0
```

After:

```
❯ pip freeze | grep notebook
notebook==7.0.5
```

Here you can see the issue:
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/7051

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and there seemed to be a problem with jupyter server for some reason. Try installing that:

```
pip install jupyter_server
```

However, that wasn't enough on my end, there also seems to be a problem with traitlets. Try updating that as well:

```
pip install --upgrade traitlets
```

Comment: Thks brother,will try this